# Get location fragment with Fetch API redirect response

Tags: redirect, oauth-2.0, webrtc, openid-connect, fetch-api

I am trying to get the redirect response location fragment of a fetch API request. But I can't figure how to access it, if possible.

The context is that I am doing an OpenID Connect request in implicit flow, for a WebRTC Identity Proxy assertion generation.
OIDC specs define the answer of the request as:

> When using the Implicit Flow, all response parameters are added to the
>   fragment component of the Redirection URI
>
> HTTP/1.1 302 Found
>    Location: https://client.example.org/cb#
>      access_token=SlAV32hkKG
>      ...

So I'm making the request with fetch set in manual mode. But the response is then an opaque-redirect filtered response, which hides the location header. (https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-filtered-response-opaque-redirect)

Other mode for fetch are error and follow which would not help. While XHR automatically follows the redirect so would not help either. I may be missing something from the fetch API, but it seems to be something hidden on purpose.

Could someone gives me a way to access this information (or a confirmation it's impossible) ?

Is there any alternative to fetch and XHR to make this request, which would allow to access the redirect location header?

Answer (score 4):

[fetch](https://github.github.io/fetch/) isn't able to polyfill the entire standard. Some notable differences include:

**Inability to set the redirect mode.**

See David Graham comment on the [Disable follow redirect](https://github.com/github/fetch/issues/137):

*This is a nice addition to the Fetch API, but we won't be able to polyfill it with XMLHttpRequest. The browser navigates all redirects before returning a result, so there is no opportunity to interrupt the redirect flow.*

**My Solution**:

1). First solution: we are sending 200 status and redirect url(in the http header) from the server and client is redirecting based on that.

2). Second solution: Server could also redirect to with 301 and redirect url. I think, This is the best solution(i.e if we consider SEO).

Answer (score 3):

Since XHR automatically / opaquely follows redirects (in the event you're using the [`whatwg-fetch` polyfill](https://github.com/github/fetch) for example), one possible solution is to check the `response.url` of the `fetch` resolution, to see if it matches a redirect location that you expect.

This only helps if the possible redirect locations are limited or match some pattern --- for instance, if you could expect at any time to be redirect to `/login`:

```js
function fetchMiddleware(response) {
  const a = document.createElement('a');
  a.href = response.url;
  if (a.pathname === '/login') {
    // ...
  } else {
    return response;
  }
}

fetch(`/api`)
  .then(fetchMiddleware)
  .then(function (response) {
    // ...
  });
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I need to access the exact URL response as it contains the access_token. So the switch would not work.

But I guess that it confirms that I can only let the redirect happen and see what's in the result.